# What are the open/close positions of this shutoff valve for my fridge water?

Tags: plumbing, refrigerator, spigot

We threw out our fridge and got a lovely new fridge which has water! and ice!

The screw connector water hose was the usual type and hooked-up fine.

The small spigot in the wall looks like this:

[image]

Vintage 1990? IDK.

Here's the thing. It was *incredibly* stuck in position zero. After puzzling for days I just applied (using comically huge tools) an insane amount of torque, order of 400 ft lb, and it moved, to position 1. It now moves freely. Set aside that mystery.

No water in the fridge.

I thought, ok, it's gotta be position 0 for water, not 1. Whatever.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Positions 0 and 1 have NO water.

On a whim I put it at position 1/2, and pressed the water button in the fridge - water.

As far as I can tell - I'm prepared to accept I've lost my mind or made a ridiculous mistake - positions 0 and 1 are "full off" and position 1/2 is "on".

What the hell is this devil-object in my house?

Could it be true that on is 1/2 ?

Comment: You could disconnect the hose and look inside the device to see what opens or closes when you turn it.  (Shut off the main supply first of course.)

Comment: If I wasn't mostly on strike I would edit the title. Adds color.

Comment: I would guess that there was a clog that cleared itself.

Comment: Normally, inline with the outlet is open.  There was probably a clog as mentioned above.

Comment: Convention is when the handle is inline with the flow direction, that's "open."

Comment: I wonder how the handle is attached to the stem on the valve.  Any chance the stem is splined, and some previous user removed it and put it back at the wrong angle?  But theoretically it wouldn't go past 1/2 then.  I dunno!

Comment: that's a great point @Huesmann - I just dontr know.   to me the handle seems super weird, it totally looks more like a pressure or steam releasae thing that you toggle up-down.  what a world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something was stuck, perhaps it was plugged with lime, since the spigot was never touched for years.

Now you gorilla-wrenched the stuck spigot and probably twisted the spindle. Therefor you need a new spigot.

Comment: If you can find an identical one , you can turn off the house water, unscrew the retaining packing nut, pull the whole thing out, and replace it with parts from another one, saving you the trouble of desoldering and resoldering the installed one.

Comment: Martin, pls don't spend your bounty all in one place!  :)

Comment: @gbronner - great tip